# How to load <script src="...."> response into variable?

Tags: javascript, html, https

My html page is making the following call:

```
<html>
  <script src="https://someURL.com/api/getData?api_key=xyz&%26format=json">
</html>
```

It returns the following response:

```
data: abc123-abc456-efg678-ertyui789
```

How do I extract the

```
abc123-abc456-efg678-ertyui789
```

part into a var, so I can use it in other calls?

(I tried jquery, but it fails with CORS error, this is the only way I could get the response from the server)

Comment: Can you post the code please?  If the response is an object, theoretically you should be able to take the value by `response.data`. Post what you tried an maybe we can help you more.

Comment: You can go with 2 Options depends on the return type. I think in your case it is JS code so you should use `$.getScript("/path-to-js", function(data) =>  { console.log(data) })`

Comment: Please show EXACTLY how it renders the data. Perhaps `window.data` is set

Answer (score -1):

```
var url ='https://someURL.com/api/getData?api_key=xyz&%26format=json',
jQuery.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               url: url,
               dataType: 'json',
               success:function(res){
                  console.log("success");
                  console.log(res.data);
            });
```

Comment: you can use JSON parser.  if you are making Jquery Ajax request by datatype= 'jsonp'. Change dataType to jsonp so your GET request.

Comment: They can't use a JSON parser, the example data they gave *was not valid JSON*. Changing the `dataType` to `jsonp` would only work if the response was JSONP … which it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can't.

The `<script>` element is designed to load a script and run it. A JSON document is not a script.

JSONP *is* a script, but if the service doesn't provide data in that format, then you can't use it.

Since an API key is involved, it is very likely that the service provides no mechanism for direct client-side access to the data because that would require that you give your *secret* key to all your visitors.

Fetch the data server-side instead.

---

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068)

---

Aside, `data: abc123-abc456-efg678-ertyui789` isn't a valid JSON document anyway so you might need a custom parser and not a JSON parser.